# C - GTK Image refresh without user focusing

Tags: c, gtk

I currently have a program that is changing an image in a gtk window. When my code changes the image, the change appears in the image as soon as I focus on the window (ie click, resize, etc.). I would like it to update without the user having to focus on the window because I am having the user input data into the terminal as the image is being changed (ie classification of subimages). Thus having to click back and forth constantly is a nuisance.

I have the window handler running in a separate thread.

Here is my code

```
static void* gtkStarter(void * a) {
 gtk_main();
  return NULL;
}

void PixelImage::show() {
  gtk_widget_show_all(this->window);
  pthread_create(&this->pp, NULL, gtkStarter, NULL);
}

void PixelImage::close() {
  gtk_widget_hide(this->window);
  gtk_main_quit();
  pthread_join(this->pp, NULL);
}

void PixelImage::refresh() {
  gtk_widget_show(this->image);
}
```

I have tried calling:

```
gtk_widget_show
gtk_widget_grab_focus
gtk_widget_realize
```

Here is how I call refresh
    Red rs (*this->p);
    Merge mm;

```
PntPxlVector *ppv = this->p->mapReduce(pp, this->radius,
                                       this->thick + this->radius,
                                       rs, mm); // Gets points for drawing a circle

for (PntPxlVector::iterator itr = ppv->begin();
     itr != ppv->end();
     itr++) { // Draws the circle and stores previous pixel values
  Pixel tmp = this->pi->get(itr->first);
  this->pi->set(itr->first, itr->second);
  itr->second = tmp;
}

this->pi->refresh(); // Refresh for circle display
feature f = this->prompt("Label? "); // Give a class label to the pixels in the circle

for (PntPxlVector::iterator itr = ppv->begin();
     itr != ppv->end();
     itr++) { // Reset the pixels to their original colors
  this->pi->set(itr->first, itr->second);
}
this->pi->refresh(); // Refresh for correct display


delete ppv; // clean up memory
return f;
```

Comment: How are you calling `refresh` ?

Comment: I posted the code that calls the refresh function. This is C++ by the way. Refresh is called in the main thread, while as shown, the gtk main is run in a separate thread

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the gtk_main() thread not running when the window is in the background

Comment: I still can't see how your threads are working.. if your gtk_main()-thread is seperated thread (not the sam thread as where you call refresh) then it's no wonder it's not working. If you would use gtkmm, I would tell you to use a dispatcher. But I couldn't find any equivalent in C. Maybe http://blog.borovsak.si/2009/06/multi-threaded-gtk-applications.html?m=1 can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about gtk Image's, but I myself use `gtk_widget_queue_draw(GtkWidget *widget)` for refreshing Cairo images, it should work for your case aswell.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. ie, nothing happens. From reading a bit, this appears to be because I am not using cairo nor any drawable surface.